# Does a downvote prevent the day from counting towards epic/legendary?

Tags: discussion

Let's say a user gets 21 upvotes and 1 downvote in a day. Does that day count as progress towards the [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic) and [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary) badges?

The reason I ask is that, when I run the query at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/32763/epic-legendary-badges, I get a different answer than from a rep audit (9 versus 13).

Comment: It may depend on the order of getting the votes.  *21 up, then 1 down =198* vs *20 up, 1 down, then 1 up =200*.

Comment: does all that matters is getting > 200 reputation, from any source?

Comment: Note: The data dump is not as fresh as your rep audit is, it is updated on an irregular, infrequent basis. Use it knowing you are possibly looking at long-since-stale information.

Comment: No, not *any* source; according to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation rep cap has to be reached from votes only, so you can get 19 up and 1 accepted answer (205) and it wont count.

Comment: @chown, the badge is only concerned with the 200 rep, notice it doesn't explicitly mention the cap. Upvote reputation is certainly limited to 200 points, but meeting or exceeding 200 is all that matters as far as badges are concerned.

Comment: @A so.com/reputation does mention rep cap from votes.  I assume that stat is there for users to track this badge progress.

Comment: A downvote a day keeps the badge away. (*evil laugh*)

Comment: It **used** to be the case that only days where you'd reached the rep cap from upvotes alone counted for epic/legendary, but that's changed now.

Comment: @ChrisF I think it was the other way around. The old text for the badge faq was [Exceeding the cap is defined as earning ≥200 reputation in one day from a combination of upvotes and accepts, but not bounties](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/67399/30).

Comment: @ConradFrix - You may be right. There was a change though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this badge has changed and now only requires ≥200 rep from ***any*** source (sans bounties), not just votes.

Evidence: [User Adam Rackis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352552/adam-rackis?tab=reputation) is the latest the earn the [epic](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/epic?userid=352552) badge and has 51 days with over 200 rep.
Two of those days (probably more but I only needed 2 to verify) upvote rep was < 200.

On Dec 30th 2011: 160 from votes + 60 from accepts (=220)
On Jan 17th 2012: 170 from votes + 45 from accepts (=215)

---

From Jeff: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge/58192#58192

> Here's the exact SQL (and the disconnect is between the SQL and the C# code) for the badge.
>
> ```
> SELECT u.id 
> FROM   users u WITH (nolock), 
>        /* return all userids who have hit the rep cap for 150 days */ 
>        (SELECT targetuserid AS userid 
>         FROM   (SELECT targetuserid, 
>                        CONVERT(CHAR(8), creationdate, 112) AS dayperiod, 
>                        SUM(targetrepchange)                AS dayrep 
>                 FROM   posts2votes 
>                 WHERE  targetrepchange IS NOT NULL 
>                        AND deletiondate IS NULL 
>                 GROUP  BY targetuserid, 
>                           CONVERT(CHAR(8), creationdate, 112) 
>                 HAVING SUM(targetrepchange) >= 200) AS x 
>         GROUP  BY targetuserid 
>         HAVING COUNT(*) >= 150) x 
> WHERE  u.id NOT IN /* return all userids who do NOT have the badge */ 
>               (SELECT userid 
>                FROM users2badges u2b WITH (nolock) 
>                INNER JOIN badges b 
>                 ON u2b.badgeid = b.id 
>                WHERE b.name = 'Legendary' 
>               ) 
>        AND u.id = x.userid
> ```

Comment: where do you get the sql?

Comment: From the link right above it.  It's a dev side query, not for the SEDE